# Map sonar components to jira components

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using Jira plugin in SonarQube. I can choose component which needs to be used in new jira issues created from sonar. But this setting is available only on sonar project level (sonar.jira.issue.component.id). On the component level this setting is missing (there is "Jira filter name" parameter only).

Is there some way how to fill in the component value in jira issues according to component value in sonar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for the moment with the current version of the JIRA plugin. Feel free to come and discuss this on the user mailing list.